# Python web scraping: I have a website with pick list. And how to pull the text in these lists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

The link is below:
https://www.doximity.com/sign_ups/9e016f85-d589-4cdf-8240-09c356d4434f/edit?sign_up[user_attributes][firstname]=Jian&sign_up[user_attributes][lastname]=Cui

I need to pull the occupation and its corresponding speciality.
But my code only works on pulling occupations.

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('https://www.doximity.com/sign_ups/9e016f85-d589-4cdf-8240-09c356d4434f/edit?sign_up[user_attributes][firstname]=Jian&sign_up[user_attributes][lastname]=Cui')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
spec = soup.find_all('select')

for sub in spec:
    print (sub.text)
```

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: You are going to need selenium for this. BeautifulSoup is not made for dynamic website interaction which is the case here i.e you have to select an occupation to get its specialities

Comment: Gotcha. I will have a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code and let me know in case of any issues:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.doximity.com/sign_ups/9e016f85-d589-4cdf-8240-09c356d4434f/edit?sign_up[user_attributes][firstname]=Jian&sign_up[user_attributes][lastname]=Cui'

driver.get(url)
spec = driver.find_element_by_id("sign_up_user_attributes_credential_id")
for sub in spec.find_elements_by_xpath('./option | ./optgroup/option'):
    if sub.get_attribute('value') != '':
        print(sub.text)
    selected_spec = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sign_up_user_attributes_credential_id"))
    selected_spec.select_by_visible_text(sub.text)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    occup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="sign_up_user_attributes_user_professional_detail_attributes_specialty_id"]')
    for oc in occup.find_elements_by_xpath('./option'):
        if oc.text != '' and oc.get_attribute('value') != '':
            print(oc.text)
```